# Based on what precedence rules is a[x].SomeMember evaluated as (a[x]).SomeMember and not…?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

a) Both dot operator ( a.x ) and index operator ( a[x] ) have the same level of precedence. So based on what precedence rules is an expression `a[x].SomeMember` evaluated as `(a[x]).SomeMember` and not as `(a.SomeMember )[x]`?

b) Is casting operator an unary operator ( and thus has lower precedence than dot operator ) and for that reason is an expression `(int)a.x`evaluated as `(int)(a.x)`?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a)

From C# Specification, section 7.2.1:

> When an operand occurs between two operators with the same precedence, the associativity of the operators controls the order in which the operations are performed:
>
> - Except for the assignment operators, all binary operators are left-associative, meaning that operations are performed from left to right. For example, x + y + z is evaluated as (x + y) + z.
> - The assignment operators and the conditional operator (?:) are right-associative, meaning that operations are performed from right to left. For example, x = y = z is evaluated as x = (y = z).

This means that the operators will get precedence, in this situation, from left to right.

b) Yes, this is correct.  This is a Cast Expression, described in section 7.6.6, which is applied to a unary expression, and casts are categorized with the Unary operators (Section 7.6) and treated with the same precedence.

Comment: For some reason I didn’t think that dot and index operators also have left associativity

Comment: Why isn’t casting considered an unary operator? After all, it has only one operand?

Comment: Well, it's an expression acted upon a unary expression.  The C# spec treats it as a unary operator. I reworded - since the C# spec treats it as unary.

Answer (score 1):

a) The precedence is a left-to-right precedence. In evaluating the references, the compiler proceeds left to right in determining which equal operators receive precedence. Since a[x] precedes [x].SomeMember it gets referenced first.

b) It is not a unary operator but it has the same precedence as a unary.

[Precedence of the C# Operators](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0060__Operator/ThePrecedenceoftheCOperators.htm)

Answer (score 1):

a) Based on the sequence of code. `a = b` is interpreted differently to `b = a` for the same reason!

b) Casting is an unary operator as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691364(VS.71).aspx). Its specific behaviour is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691370(VS.71).aspx).